# Can't disable configurable product variations in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

When I edit a `configurable product` in the `Configuration section`, it shows the list of all the configurations.

I want to disable one of the products listed there so when I  choose `Disable Product` the status does change to "Disabled".

But after saving the product, status changes back to `Enabled`.

I have the error logs enabled but `no error message` appears there even when I have cleared the cache and reindexed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. After I've tried to change simple products statuses, from the configurable product grid, I've encountered the same problem. Seems to be a magento bug.

**The story**

Before saving the informations about configurable product, there are initialised the informations about simple products belonging to it. This is happening in `module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/UpdateConfigurations.php` file, following function:

```
private function getConfigurationsFromProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $configurableProduct)
    {
        $result = [];

        $configurableMatrix = $configurableProduct->hasData('configurable-matrix') ?
            $configurableProduct->getData('configurable-matrix') : [];
        foreach ($configurableMatrix as $item) {
            if (empty($item['was_changed'])) {
                continue;
            } else {
                unset($item['was_changed']);
            }

            if (!$item['newProduct']) {
                $result[$item['id']] = $this->mapData($item);

                if (isset($item['qty'])) {
                    $result[$item['id']]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'] = $item['qty'];
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Here, the simple products are iterated and if a product contains `was_changed`, in the array informations, it is added in the `$result` array to be saved in the database.

**The problem**: Even if I change the status for a simple product, the `was_changed` attribute is not set for it, in the informations which will be received by the "save" controller. So, when the simple items are iterated in `getConfigurationsFromProduct` function, the `continue` statement will be hit every time, `$result` array being null.

**The solution**:

I've found a way to set `was_changed` attribute, in the `toggleStatusProduct` function from `module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/dynamic-rows-configurable.js`, which is dispatched every time the simple product status is changed. The cleanest way is to rewrite that file and replace the function with:

```
toggleStatusProduct: function (rowIndex) {
            var tmpArray = this.getUnionInsertData(),
                status = parseInt(tmpArray[rowIndex].status, 10);

            if (status === 1) {
                tmpArray[rowIndex].status = 2;
            } else {
                tmpArray[rowIndex].status = 1;
            }
            tmpArray[rowIndex]['was_changed'] = true;
            this.unionInsertData(tmpArray);
        }
```

Clear the cache, run a deploy and it should work.

Good luck !

Comment: Perfect, that fixes it! How do I overwrite that? When I add the file app/design/frontend/Meigee/blacknwhite/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/view/adminhtml/web/js/components it doesn't overwrite.

Comment: try to run a php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy followed by php bin/magento cache:clean. Also clear the browser cache

Comment: If it's working, please be a fair player and mark the answer accordingly !! :D

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I had.  Would clicking Clean Cache in the backend do the same as running the php bin/magento cache:clean command?

Comment: No problem :D ...yes, it's the same thing

Comment: is there any official patch yet?